# Content data does not load properly on ckeditor4 in react

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor4.x

What's wrong with this code, Sometimes the data not shown on the Ckeditor and sometimes it shows.
I already make sure that the data will fetch successfully from the database but they will not load sometimes on the Ckeditor. Its not stable, it will show but when I reload again it does not show again.

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import CKEditor from 'ckeditor4-react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Edit(props) {

const [dataaddinfo, setdataaddinfo] = useState('');

function Textinfo(id){
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('type','getinfo');
  formData.append('id',id);
  axios.post('/url/info.php',formData)
  .then(function (response) {
    let obj = response.data;
    setdataaddinfo(obj.addinfo);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
}

useEffect(()=>{
    Textinfo(5);
},[]);

return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CKEditor
          onBeforeLoad={ ( CKEDITOR ) => ( CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true ) }
          data={dataaddinfo}
       />
    </React.Fragment>
)
}
```

Comment: There seems to be no problem with the code. Please check the console logs when you are reloading the page. If the component is getting mounted again api call will be happening. When you are saying reloading i am understanding that component is getting unmounted and mounted. Please correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: I already checked and observed if the data is fetch every reload process and its fine. The data is consistently fetch. However, I have no idea why not loading to ckeditor.
I already ouput the data not on ckeditor and the data successfully outputed. And I have a feeling that the problem is on ckeditor.

Comment: Yes might be , if the console.log is always working there might be some issue with CkEditor

Comment: i using "react-ckeditor-component" and fine work i!

Comment: @JavadKhodadadi thanks that works for me, however i can't edit the content if i remove the content paramater it works for editing. <CKEditor activeClass="p10" content={datadescription} events={{"blur"(evt)=>EventDescription(evt),"afterPaste": (evt)=> EventDescription(evt),"change": (evt)=> EventDescription(evt) }} />